# Why is $Ker(a \phi)$ a $\phi$-invariant $K$-subvectorspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $K$ be a field, $\phi:V \to V$ a vectorspaceendomorphism, $n \in \mathbb N$

Is the following statement always true?

For $a \in K$ is $Ker(a \phi)$ a $\phi$-invariant $K$-subvectorspace of V.

**Question:**
Why is that true?

**My guess:**

if $Ker(a\phi) \neq 0 $ and $ \phi(Ker(a \phi))=0$

$\Rightarrow \phi(Ker(a\phi))\neq Ker(a\phi)$

So $Ker(a\phi)$ is not a $\phi$-invariant $K$-subvectorspace of V.

**Note:** 
This question is related to that [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384290/2-dimensional-phi-invariant-k-subvectorspace-in-v-if-v-is-finite-dime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector subspace $W$ is $\phi$-invariant if and only if $\phi(W)\subseteq W$ (this is the definition).

For $a\ne 0$, $$\phi(\ker(a\phi))=\phi(\ker\phi)=\{0\}\subseteq \ker (a\phi)$$
For $a=0$, $$\phi(\ker 0)=\phi(V)\subseteq V=\ker 0$$

Comment: Why is $\phi(ker 0) = \phi(V)$?

Comment: because a = 0  , which means  , for any  v in V  ist a$\phi(v)$ = 0 which means kern(a $\phi$)= kern(0)=V